# User profile layout vs. contact form option

Tags: users, emails

On the user profile I have some 12 fields for the users to enter their contact information and other details about themselves. The option to activate/deactivate the personal contact form is somwhere between the fouth and the fith field.

I would like to have to personal contact form option to be on a position I intend it to be on – e.g. the first position, before all other fields, since it's an option – and not a field. Disabling the drag'n'drop i can actually rearrange the fields in the intended order. But when I switch drag'n'drop field sorting back on, the checkbox jumps back down somewhere between field four and five.

Any suggestions anybody? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

found the answer / an answer to my question: Installing and enabling the module profile2 helped. The missing fields ("Contact user element") showed up in the fields list and became sortable through drag'n'drop.